# WPF MultiSelect ComboBox IDataErrorInfo Validation

Tags: wpf, validation, combobox, idataerrorinfo

I have a UserControl which gives functionality for MultiSelectComboBox (implements SelectedItemsProperty,ItemsSourceProperty DependencyProperties).

My ViewModel, implements IDataErrorInfo and uses DataAnnotations to validate, has a property that binds to SelectedItems of the UserControl.

My problem is validation isn't working. IDataErrorInfo's this[propertyname] is never fired on selecteditems changed event, but only when window is loaded.

Is there a way to pass on the validationfrom user control to viewmodel or how do I force validation in viewmodel?

Comment: I found it.
Adding the Mode=TwoWay to Binding solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
Adding the Mode=TwoWay to Binding solved the issue.